# How are Simple Certificate Enrollment Protocol (SCEP) used in real world?

Tags: certificate, ssl-certificate

I am new to certificates. I am learning about certificates using Google. I have an overview about certificates. Now I've started going through SCEP.

Before starting it I am trying to get to know how SCEP is used in real world. In Google I couldn't find the exact use cases for it.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the following links..

For full information on SCEP
Visit https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-nourse-scep-18#page-5

Highlevel information on SCEP
visit http://www.slideshare.net/iveslaaf/3-scep